# Google maps no empty tiles, no map, no LogCat errors. Map API V2 6/2013

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

My map wont show up.  I DONT even get a map grid nor any error messages in the Log Cat.  I do not get any type of “Failed to authenticate via google api” or anything like that (which makes me believe my api key is correct).  I simply don’t get any type of map.

Configuration & Manifest

1. I am using the android emulator (I retrived the debug key to generate my API key since im not exporting this as an apk)
2. I appropriately got the SHA1 from jdk1.7 and debug keystore
3. I enabled both GoogleMaps V2 and GooglMapsAndroidV2 on the API developer console
4. I enabled all required and recommended permissions, meta-data, and features (such as openGL 2) as shown below in my manifest
5. I have enabled Android PrivateLibraries
   a.  Google-play-services.jar
   b.  Android-support-v4.jar
6. I have Android Dependencies: 
   a.  Google-play-services_lib.jar
7. I have coppied my project.properties and proguard file at the bottom of this post

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.proximitystuff"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.proximitystuff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.proximitystuff.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.example.proximitystuff.MyMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAPACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.proximitystuff.ProxyBackgroundCheck"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="com.example.ADAMS_PROX_PERMISSION" >
        </service>

       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBnQNgn166qfatch_xcFwL8K0AfVHBYcGA"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java Code and XML layout:
My main activity uses a button to go into the map activity shown in the screenshot.  The code for this map activity is stipped to the most basic functionality and it still wont work.  One theory I had was that since this class doesn’t inherit from “FragmentActivity” it woulndt be able to work with the xml fragment (I expect I would get at least some type of error in the log if this was the case).

```
package com.example.proximitystuff;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MyMapActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);
    }
}

My XML layout is using the most basic layout possible. 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

[image]

Project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

Proguard (just in case this is wrong):

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {

protected Object[][] getContents();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently I was being an idiot and had:

2 api keys registered to the same SHA1 and the same package name... Basically i registered the app for API access twice (on the API console) and arbitrarily chose one of those API keys for my manifest (Big "no no" evidently).

So it looks like only one API key per map or you will have a non-functioning app without any log errors. You also wont see any tiles (empty or not). Thanks for the help, hopefully this saves someone the hours of trial and error i went through.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using the android emulator

AFAIk, the Android emulator does not support Maps V2, or anything involving Play Services. While they have announced a resolution this, I am unaware that an updated image has been released.

Comment: Wow! that sounds incredibly inconvenient...  Where did you see this documentation (I'm surprised i haven't found it)?  i seem to remember the emulator working flawlessly with API version 1.

On another note: When I create a release apk and run in on my pantech flex (Running ICS). I seem to get empty tiles (I registered my release SHA1 to optain a new API key that i replaced with the debug).  did you see any problems in my post that could be the cause of this?

Thank you very much, its an honor to have such an expert as yourself take the time to answer this question.

Comment: @adamkim: "i seem to remember the emulator working flawlessly with API version 1" -- Maps V1 and Maps V2 are not related in terms of emulator support. "did you see any problems in my post that could be the cause of this?" -- your `<permission>` (`com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE`) does not match the corresponding `<uses-permission>` (`com.example.proximitystuff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE`), which might explain it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  I copied and pasted that code in the hopes that there was a typo i was originally missing (looks like that backfired).  Unfortunately the problem persists.  I did misspeak though, its not the "empty tiles issue", ite more of a no tiles and no background issue.  I'll keep looking although i dont know what else to look for

Comment: @adamkim: FWIW, here's a directory full of Maps V2 samples known to work: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2

Comment: Could the problem be that im using my jdk1.7 to create the key when apps are running 1.6 compliance?  I dont think i even have a 1.6 compiler

Answer (score 1):

Use Android phone to test application rather than using emulator and try following tutorial..its really helpful..

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html